# balanced payments test credit cards

Tags: balanced-payments

I was using these test credit cards using the secret API Key shown in my dashboard. 
https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/overview/resources/#test-credit-card-numbers

They were all giving intended response but all of sudden they are giving success status for every card#. I was using the invalid card/frozen card, CVV mismatch etc.. Now all of these cards are giving success status. Any idea what might be wrong ?

Thanks,
VInay

Answer (score 3):

The test credit cards are always able to be tokenize successfully. If there is a CVV mismatch, the `cvv_match` field will read 'No'. If there is a postal code AVS mismatch, `avs_postal_match` will indicate this, and so on. The decision about whether to accept cards with AVS/CVV match failures is left up to the marketplace.